# Show positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

On the complex vector space $C([0,1], \mathbb{C})$ one defines a scalar product $<f,g>:=\int_0^1 f(t)\bar{g(t)}dt$. How do I show that this bilinear form is positive definite?
I. e. how do I deduce $\int_0^1|f(t)|^2dt > 0$ for $f\neq 0$ ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably mean $f(t) \overline{g(t)} dt$, or you mean $C([0,1], \mathbb R)$. Which one is it?

Comment: I do mean the complex conjugate of g(t), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A non-negative function integrates to zero if and only if its zero almost everywhere. Note that $|f(t)|^2 \geq 0$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769510/x-nonnegative-and-integral-equal-to-zero-implies-measure-of-positive-part-zero), for example, for details.

Comment: But the integral should not be zero, but >0. I think I need that f is continous and could show it in case $f(t)\in \mathbbR$ (with the corresponding scalar product, see first comment to my question), but in the complex case I'm confused.

Comment: Yes. The integral of a non-negative function is obviously non-negative (since if $f \geq g$, $\int f \geq \int g$ and take $g=0$). Once you use the hint, it will show that $\int_0^1 |f(t)|^2 =0$ if and only if $|f(t)|^2 =0$, which occurs if and only if $|f(t)|=0$ which occurs if and only if $f(t)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but still $f\neq 0$ could also imply that $f$ is zero everywhere exept for one $x_0$. But then the integral would be zero according to your hint. Why is $|f(t)|^2$ not almost zero everywhere, then?

Comment: You can't have a continuous function be zero almost everywhere without being zero everywhere, continuity does that

Comment: That can't happen due to continuity - if $|f(t)| >0$ at $x_0$, then by continuity, I can find $\epsilon>0$ such that for $|t-x_0|< \epsilon$, $|f(t)-f(x_0)| < |f(x_0)|/2$, so $|f(t)|$ would be non-zero on a set of measure at least $\epsilon$.