# Explanation of measure space and positive measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Consider the measure space $(, , )$ and $$ a measurable function
positive. Prove that:
$ ∫    =  0 ↔  =  0$

@MISC {769933,
TITLE = {X nonnegative and integral equal to zero implies measure of positive part zero},
AUTHOR = {Davide Giraudo (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9849/davide-giraudo)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
NOTE = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/769933 (version: 2014-04-26)},
EPRINT = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/769933},
URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/769933}
}
I have found this answer in the forum, my question is, how is the σ-subadditivity property of a measure applied to said identity?
${x∈Ω:f(x)>0}=⋃_n⩾1{x∈Ω:f(x)⩾1/n}$.
Is this demo incomplete?

Comment: I think you meant to say $f\geq0$.

Comment: The identity is illegible, and I don’t know why you’ve got some (JSON?) programming data in the middle of your post

Comment: Hello, what happens is that I wanted to quote that publication and they would solve my doubts regarding that demonstration, it seems incomplete.

Comment: For a fixed integer $n$, we consider the simple function
$f_n:x → 1/n X {y,f(y)≥1/n}$ This is a simple nonnegative function, a function that is less than or equal to $f$, therefore$ μ{y,f(y)≥1/ n=0}$ since
${f>0}=∪_(n≥1) {y,f(y)≥1/n}$
We obtain by σ-sub-additivity that $μ{f>0}=0$